# how to change the grails version for a project in GGTS

Tags: ggts

When you create a new project using GGTS (on windows), it gives you the option to chose the Grails version in the new project wizard.

However, I chose the default 2.4.2, but my project was built on 2.3.2, and I want to change it back. I cant find any project property when I can change the grails version.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the app.grails.version property in the application.properties file, found in the top level of the project directory.

```
app.grails.version=2.3.2
```

GGTS will prompt you to configure the correct path to Grails if the app.grails.version doesn't match the currently configured Grails distributions.